# Show that if B and C have two equal rows, then AC and BC have two equal rows as well

Tags: linear-algebra

Heres the problem in my textbook:
Show that if B and C have two equal columns, and A is any matrix for which AB and AC are defined, then AB and AC also have two equal columns.

This wasn't hard to figure out.  But the question also says "Find a similar result involving matrices with two equal rows."  I've tested this with matrices that can multiply and found this only works if B and C are equal.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Try multiplying on the right, i.e. $BA$ and $CA$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $BA$ and $CA$. 
If we know that $AB$ and $AC$ have some equal column, then $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ and $(AC)^T=C^T A^T$ have the equal row.

Answer (score 2):

You have to find a similar result for $B$ and $C$ with equal rows, so not the same result.

And note that if $B$ and $C$ have equal rows, $B^T$ and $C^T$ have equal columns.